# Rich push issue when having multiple notification service extension

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am having two notification service extension (Onesignal and Fcm), when triggering notification from fcm its getting received without image or video. If onesignal service extension is removed fcm rich push is working fine. Is there a way to keep and use both.

• Tried removing onesignal service extension at this time FCM rich push is working.

• Expecting to keep both notification service and receive rich push from FCM.